# Collection of(multiple) route params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute, routeparams

This route config

```
URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
```

would result in: `{chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}`

Is it possible however to have a collection of objects trough `$routeParams` like:

```
 [
   {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'},
   {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'5', search:'mobydick'}
 ]
```

and what would be the route configuration to achieve it?

Comment: are you using `ui-router`/`ngRoute` API?

Comment: @PankajParkar `ngRoute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a somewhat solution myself:

**url**:

```
domain#/foo/whatever?id=1&id=2&name=Moo&name=Boo
```

**route config**

```
$routeProvider.when('/foo/whatever', {
  templateUrl: 'whatever.html',
  controller: 'WhatEverCtrler'
});
```

**controller**:

```
module.controller('WhatEverCtrler',['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
  console.log('routeParams: ', $routeParams);
  // logs --> Object {id: Array[2], name: Array[2]}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$location.search()`

In your example it would look like this:

```
var searchObject = $location.search(); // => {search: 'moby'}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search), they have a nice example